# Flash .exe projector on a cd, memory issues

Tags: actionscript-3, cd, dvd

I'm working with a project where we are running a projector from/on a CD, and this can't be changed, to run an e-learning program of sorts. Everything is included on the CD and it doesn't need anything else to run, ie all imgs and xml and whatnot is on the CD.
The problem is that on some computers, assumedly less powerful ones, the entire process clogs up and instead of showing the images just white blank areas appear. The imgs used have been downgraded to a lower resolution, from 1333x1000 to 800x600, and this has solved the problem from what we've found so far.

My question is, does anyone know of any other way to solve this without cutting down the img quality?

As it is right now all the pics (about 180 i think) are being loaded right when the process starts and one idea i have is that you load the pics gradually as needed, 2-3 in advance back and forward or maybe an entire chapter even (7 chapters with imgs are used), to always ensure smooth tweens without having to wait for loading.
But as I've read that there seems to be some memory issue when using a flash projector on a CD/DVD, I'd also like to get more details on what the actual problem is and if possible to find more solutions to it.

I found some links that were supposed to target Adobes own views on the problem, but these links were obsolete. (links found here http://www.flashjester.com/?section=faq&cPath=14_23#394).

Any ideas, help, links, tutorials and what not are welcome.

Comment: Are you preloading the images? On a slower computer they might not show up because they haven't loaded yet.  But I think your idea of loading just a few at a time is a good one.  Make sure you dump them when you're done with them to save memory.

Comment: Yes in the current version all 186 imgs get preloaded first thing. Ie you can't get to the rest of the "program" before they're done loading.  
I'm a bit worried about not loading them all from the start, as CD/DVD players don't always start loading data instantenously and there is a small setup section where you can decide which imgs to show for each chapter where you can click each thumbnail to get to the view of the actual img.

Comment: So you can quite quickly just change to another chapter via a tab, and at that point the imgs needs to load / be loaded too so you can click any of them and it'll show without any delay. Meaning i'm not sure it'll be fast enough to load all imgs belonging to a specific chapter...  with the issue of them being loaded from the CD/DVD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you need to load your assets on-demand and be careful about references so unused things are really garbage collected when they aren't needed anymore.

If you are really running from a projector, then load times aren't totally a concern.  Assets form the local filesystem are always available the next frame; they aren't streamed from the disk like from the network.  However, bigs file or ones with lots of exports may end up with a longer frame time, or a noticeable delay.

You also need profile things to see if your changes are actually doing anything.  Poke through the [flash.system.System](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/System.html) class to see how you can get info, or take a look at [SWFProfiler](http://www.lostinactionscript.com/blog/index.php/2008/10/06/as3-swf-profiler/).

Comment: Thanks. Like i wrote in my comment above, i'm not sure it'll be fast enough to load the imgs on demand from the CD/DVD, but it seems likely it'd solve the memory issue if it was possible.
Will definently run the SWFProfiler to see what i get from that :-)